# Torque and Pulleys

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, rotational-kinematics

[image]

[image]

I have the solution to the problem below, however I approached the question differently than my professor and I do not understand why my answer is different. Can someone help explain where I'm going wrong in my solution.

[image]

I do not understand what I did wrong. Please help my understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that the two tensions are different, because of the presence of a pulley with non-zero $I$. What you have missed is:

1) connect the two tensions to the torque: $(T_1-T_2)R=I\alpha$

and

2) link the accelerations $R\alpha=a_1=a_2$

NOTE (from comments): 
If the pulley   had a zero $I$ (moment of inertia), then  the two tensions would be be the same: you can see that if you put $I=0$ on the first equation, it results in $T_1=T_2$. Also, in such a case, $\alpha$ is not necessarily zero (for the results of this exercice that is irrelevant): nothings precludes a disk with very small $I$ to rotate, or a small mass to accelerate. Zero is actually an idealization, what is meant is that it is so mall that you do not even consider it.

Comment: Just as a side question: So if I had a pulley with had a zero I (moment of inertia), then would the two tensions be the same? From what I understand from your answer they would be the same.

Comment: yes, and you can see that if you put I=0 on the first equation, it results in T1=T2

Comment: If I is 0, than alpha must be zero as well right? So if a pulley has 0 moment of inertia, it wouldn't rotate?

Comment: No, alpha is not necessarily zero (for the results of this exercice that is irrelevant), but nothings precludes a disk from very small I to rotate, or a small mass to accelerate. Zero is actually an idealization, what is meant is that it is so mall that you do not even consider it.

Answer (score 0):

The tension in the rope should be different on the left than on the right - it is this difference that gives rise to the torque that accelerates the pulley. You seem to think that it should be the same: but if it was, then where would the torque to move the pulley come from?

Annotate your diagram carefully: you did not show $T$ anywhere.